# Software life-cycle models used today

Tags: models, agile

For the past 3 semesters at school I've been taking software engineering classes where we've been learning about the various life-cycle models. The textbook for the course is a collection of IEEE articles from the 1970s and 1980s. The professors has a generally negative attitude towards just about every model. He says they are all useless. The main models we talk about are waterfall, evolutionary, incremental, spiral, and my favorite (sarcasm), the automated software synthesis model.

My questions:

- **What are some other models used today** (even if only in theory, as in the case of automatic software synthesis)?

and

- **What is the most prevalent model used for large projects in the industry** (Google, Microsoft, Apple, etc.)?

I hear a lot of people talk about using Agile, but more often than not I get the impression that they're not really talking about an actual life-cycle model. I think most of the time people just mean that they don't design or document like they should...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this questions on programmers (which was closed, but still an excellent reference starting point): [Are there any major alternatives to waterfall and Agile?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11512/are-there-any-major-alternatives-to-waterfall-and-agile)

Nearly all of these lifecycle models have been used successfully in industry on large projects, some more easily than others.  Choice of lifecycle model depends on many factors including size, cost, safety concerns, time, volatility, "researchiness" of the project, risk, stakeholders, schedule needs, etc and may vary from project to project, even within the same company.